# Two sets of users (teacher and student) in Django authentication

Tags: python, django

I'm building a web application where I have 2 sets of users (students and teachers). Teachers should be able to create their account, create a page of their content. Students should be able to create an account to sign up for this content. I am currently using django-registration to handle registration but I am wondering what's the best way to handle these 2 sets of users and still be able to use the Django authentication framework? I have heard about having multiple profiles but would like some opinions.

Thanks!

Comment: That's what groups are for.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#groups Why aren't you using groups?

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was uncertain about how the models overlapped but I will be implementing them using groups.

Comment: "how the models overlapped"?  What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use permissions. When they sign up if they're a Teacher give them content creation permissions. If they're a student they don't get the permissions.

In the user profile I would just have a field that says which type they are. Unless a lot of the data is different I wouldn't have two user profiles.

Comment: What about like using Groups and grouping them instead? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Yup, and then set the permissions on the group level.