# how to make USERNAME field unique for multiple type of users in User Model

Tags: python, django

I have followed these [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926922/how-to-set-up-django-models-with-two-types-of-users-with-very-different-attribut),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494481/django-teacher-students-easy-solution-use-separate-tables-or-permissions-and-g),[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033067/two-sets-of-users-teacher-and-student-in-django-authentication) links to create a custom user model by extending `AbstractBaseUser` class. I am storing login information of three type of users lets say teacher, Admin and students in this table. `USERNAME` field is `emailId`.
I want to make `emailId` unique among one type of users. In other words, in my system student can register as teacher as well with same `emailId`. But since `emailId` is `USERNAME` field and hence unique, I am unable to achieve this.
Please suggest how can I do this in Django application.

UserModel :

```
class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_type_choices = (
        (constants.USER_TYPE_ADMIN, 'Admin'),
        (constants.USER_TYPE_INSTITUTE, 'Institute'),
        (constants.USER_TYPE_STUDENT, 'Student')
    )
    sys_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)        
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, null=False, blank=False)    
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=127, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)  
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=user_type_choices, null=False, blank=True) 
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'mobile', 'user_type','is_staff']
```

I am using other models like StudentsDetails, TeacherDetails with foreign key to UserModel to store extra information.

Comment: Remove unique on the email field and use `unique_together` in the Meta class.

Comment: USERNAME field must have unique=True

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're stuck.